# Converting swift 1.2 code to swift 2: Missing argument label in call

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, swift

I'm getting a "Missing argument label 'rawValue:' in call" error while trying to set the authorisation header for an API authentication project based on this tutorial (https://www.raywenderlich.com/85528/user-accounts-ios-ruby-rails-swift#next_section).

This is the code in question with the issue at the

```
let base64EncodedString = utf8str?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(0))
```

Full code:

```
switch authType {
  case .HTTPBasicAuth:
    // Set BASIC authentication header
    let basicAuthString = "\(HTTPHelper.API_AUTH_NAME):\(HTTPHelper.API_AUTH_PASSWORD)"
    let utf8str = basicAuthString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    let base64EncodedString = utf8str?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(0))

    request.addValue("Basic \(base64EncodedString!)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
  case .HTTPTokenAuth:
    // Retrieve Auth_Token from Keychain
    if let userToken = KeychainAccess.passwordForAccount("Auth_Token", service: "KeyChainService") as String? {
      // Set Authorization header
      request.addValue("Token token=\(userToken)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    }
  }
```

The full code can be found here (https://codeshare.io/uJPcX) at line 50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
let base64EncodedString = utf8str?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(0))
```

to:

```
let base64EncodedString = utf8str?.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
```